# Bad invocation while minifying a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, minify

I try to minify js.file and I faced with the warning "**Bad invocation**".

this is the line that a warning was detected.

```
      if ((0, d.addClass)(t.body, "stop-scrolling"), (0, p.resetInput)(), a === n) return (0, f.logStr)("Hello!"), !1;
```

What is wrong here ?

Regards.

Comment: "JavaScript" is one word so as not to be confused with a "Java" script.

Comment: I would include the unminified version where this section exists. I imagine it's not a massive segment of code. This is like reading a foreign language.